# Can't update using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TextBox within my EditItemTemplate in my listview_car:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("photo1") %>' Visibile="true">
  </asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Now in the code I have this in my ItemUpdating event:

```
 protected void listview_car_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
   var txt1 = listview_car.Items[0].FindControl("txt1") as TextBox;
   txt1.Text = "newImage";
 }
```

Now I have debugged it and the value that is showing from my DB is correct, then when I set it from the code using `txt1.Text = "newImage";` it shows it has updated the textbox in the Auto's however it does not update in the DB, but the strange thing is when I type in the textbox and click the edit button it updates but doesn't update when I set the string in the code?

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the full code that EditItemTemplate belongs to? What's the data source?

Comment: Is your goal to enable an end user to type in the textbox and have asp.net update the database with their entry when they click the Update button?

Comment: @LonProsser No, when the user uploads an image it'll set the image fileName in the textbox and then it'll upload the fileName to the DB

Comment: @Piyush Basically setting the txt1.Text = "newImage" does not update the DB but when I edit the text through the textbox like a user would it updates, but doesnt update using txt1.Text = "newImage"

Comment: @Piyush Okay. So I have a textbox with the Text property of "<%# Bind("photo1")%>" this retrieves the photo1 column in the database and stores it in the textbox.Text property.. Now in the ItemUpdating event I want to change the Text property to "newImage" and update the database but it does not work. However if I manually go on the textbox and type in newImage and click update it updates!

Comment: I have added a video to help show my situation further.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDOKpVAm8es @Piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ItemUpdating() is called all values were already collected in the NewValues collection. To modify any of values you should modify e.NewValues

```
protected void listview_car_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues["key"] = "newImage";
}
```

where "key" is a name of the key (not a name of the control) which is usually a column name. You could also use an index 0,1,2...

Comment: But that's updating the column, I want to store the string in a textbox for now so I can do IF statements to check what I need for example if(textbox.Text = "defaultcar.jpg")

Answer (score -1):

In listview_car_ItemUpdating, first update the database, then call whatever method you used to bind your controls to the database when the page first loaded. This will retrieve the new value of photo1 from the database and bind it to txt1.

Comment: The reason why I am binding in the EditItemTemplate is so I don't touch the database at all, I want to accomplish this using the CommandName="edit"